# Mongodb crud with an ionic application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ionic-framework, crud

I created a database on a remote server. I created a js file to connect to the database using `mongoose`, `express`, `body-parser`. 
I made a connection to the remote server with the following command:

```
mongoose.connect ("mongodb: //176.31.212.51: 27017 / db")
```

I test the connection and I have a successful connection,
I launched a "listener" to listen on the port as follows:

```
app.listen (process.env.PORT)
```

with the port = `3000`
I tested and I got an error.
Is there any solution to make a successful connection with the ionic application to do the operations of CRUD?

Comment: Can you update your question with relevant code?

Comment: `mongoose.connect ("mongodb: //176.31.212.51: 27017 / db")`, if this is your actual code (with space), don't use space

Comment: no, there is no space in this line of code

Comment: What is the error that you get while starting the express server?